# Why $v \cdot p$ = 1, where $p$ is the projection of $u$. (with example)

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

In the following example, i've derived my prove as follows: however i made the conclusion that in the final step $(v \cdot p) = 1$ to derive my LHS. If possible, how can i also take out the minus sign at the final step so that i get my LHS $=$ $(u \cdot v)^2$. Thanks.

> Prove that $(u \cdot v)^2 = ||u||^2 ||v||^2 - ||u-p||^2 ||v||^2$,
>   where $p$ is the projection of $u$ on the subspace $V =$ span{$v$}.
>   Assume $x ≠ 0$.

To prove the above, i've attempted to start from the RHS, because the LHS seems to be more tedious.

I was finding a way to change the projection $p$ away, but to no avail. I do know that that the projection is $u = n + p$, where $n$ is a vector orthogonal to $V$.

I thought of taking $n = u - p$, and as such $(u-p) \cdot p = 0$, as seen below:

**RHS**

= $||u||^2 ||v||^2 - ||u-p||^2 ||v||^2$

= $ (u \cdot u) \cdot (v \cdot v) - (u-p) \cdot (u-p) \cdot (u-p) \cdot (v \cdot v)$

= $ (u \cdot u) \cdot (v \cdot v) - (v \cdot v)[u \cdot (u-p) - p \cdot (u-p)] $

= $ (u \cdot u) \cdot (v \cdot v) - (v \cdot v)[u \cdot (u-p)] $

= $ (v \cdot v) [(u \cdot u) - (u \cdot u) - (u \cdot p)] $

= $ -(v \cdot v) \cdot (u \cdot p) $

= $ (u \cdot v)^2 \cdot (v \cdot p)^2 $

I guess i'm pretty much done, but i need to prove that $(v \cdot p) = 1$, how do i do that? I know that v lies on V. Even so, how do i remove the minus sign from the equation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues to consider:-

First, the minus sign is a simple arithmetic error: $(u \cdot u) \cdot (v \cdot v) \color{red}{-} (v \cdot v)[u \cdot (u\color{red}-p)]=(v \cdot v)[(u \cdot u) - (u \cdot u) \color{red}{+} (u\cdot p)]=(v\cdot v)(u\cdot p)$

Secondly, projection vector $p$ is (by definition) the unit vector times the projection of $u$ onto $v$ - your assumption of $(p\cdot v)=1$ is incorrect :-
$$p=\frac{(u\cdot v)}{||v||^2}v$$

Putting all these together, we have
$$(v\cdot v)(u\cdot p)=||v||^2\frac{(u\cdot v)(u\cdot v)}{||v||^2}=(u\cdot v)^2$$